# Changing the title "number at risk" size in survminer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the survminer package and I want to change the font size of the "number at risk" title for the risk table. The size is too big.

```
library(survminer)
p<- ggsurvplot(fit, data = final,
                  size = 0.8, 
                  censor= FALSE, 
                  font.main = 10,
                  #font.x = 10,
                  #font.y =10,

                  legend = c (0.25,0.2), 
                  legend.title = "number", 
                  legend.labs = c ("0", "1","2","3","4","5",">=6"),

                  risk.table = TRUE, risk.table.y.col = "strata", 
                  risk.table.height = 0.3,
                  fontsize =2.5, 

                  xlim = c(0, 4), 
                  xlab = "Time in years",
                  ylab = "Treatment failure-free survival", 
                  surv.scale="percent",
                  break.time.by=1,
                  tables.theme = theme_cleantable())
p$table <-   p$table + 
  theme(
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()#removes the axis on the risk table
  )
p$plot <- p$plot + theme(legend.key.height = unit(0.58, "line")) 
ggsave(file = "ggsurv.p.tiff", print(p))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PoGibas I have found that I can use theme_cleantable and use this code to change the size of the "Number at risk" title:

```
plot$table + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=12))
```

Answer (score 5):

Change default theme. Default theme is `theme_survminer()` you have to change argument `font.main` there, for example `theme_survminer(font.main = 20)`.

Plot generate using default `survminer` data and code:

```
library(survminer)
require("survival")
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE)
```

[image]

Font size changed (`font.main`) to `20`:

```
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE, 
    tables.theme = theme_survminer(font.main = 20)) + 
    ggtitle("FOO")
```

[image]

Comment: I see in `?ggsurvplot` there's a `tables.theme` argument - can you apply the theme there so it doesn't affect the upper part of the plot?

Comment: Do you mean - survp$table <- survp$table + theme(font.main=16) ? I only want to change the font for the "Number at risk" title. I have been able to change the font size for the plot x and y axis and for the contents of the risk table.

Comment: @Marius Mariau, thanks, I edited my answer with only modifying table title.

Comment: thank you @PoGibas. That works well. The only problem I have is I cant seem to use     tables.theme = theme_cleantable())    which I was using to get rid of the axis and lines for the risk table. Is there a way to use both themes?

Comment: @sar no it won't work with `theme_cleantable` you have to pick one.